# Multiple entities for same table causes inconsistency during read

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have 2 entities for the same table and they each have their own JpaRepository. I update the data using the first entity and then read the same data using the second entity. On the read, I do not get the updated value. What can I do so that I get the latest value?

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Person")
Person1{
   private Long id;
   private String name;
}
@Entity
@Table(name="Person")
Person2{
   private Long id;
   private String name;
}
public interface Person1Repository extends JpaRepository<Person1, Long>
public interface Person2Repository extends JpaRepository<Person2, Long>
```

Current value of record in db:

```
ID, NAME
1   tom
```

This is what I am doing:

```
@Transactional
public void doSomething() {
    Person1 person1 = person1Repo.findById(1l); // value of name is tom
    person1.setName("tom1"); // value of name is updated to tom1
    person1Repo.save(person1);
    Person2 person2 = person2Repo.getById(1l); // value of name is still tom and not tom1
}
```

Comment: Either your FlushMode is `MANUAL`/`COMMIT` or you loaded `Person2` with this ID before `person1.setName()`. Actual `save()` isn't relevant - it does nothing if the entity is already persisted. BTW, in your mapping you don't say that they are mapped to the same table.

Comment: @StanislavBashkyrtsev I have not set the FlushMode explicitly to anything. So I am assuming it's using the default mode. In my mapping, I left out the Table annotation for brevity. I have added it now.

Comment: Could you enable the logging of SQL - maybe you'll find some extra SELECT before the UPDATE?

Comment: Try force flushing the changes made when saving person1 (saveAndFlush)- you are in a transaction, so the context might not be flushed until commit. As mentioned in other comments, person2 might have already been loaded - JPA maintains levels of caching at the transaction layer as well as a shared 2nd layer, so you may need to force refreshing the entity from the database - use entityManager.refresh(person2), though I don't know if Spring has logic to call this - you may have to write a custom method to access it.